# Get list of dict from mongodb insted of cursor or object

Tags: python, mongodb, list, dictionary, object

I am doing a query in mongodb using find() and i am getting pymongo cursor object and then i have to convert into list in python. Is there any way to get directly list of dictionary?

I am doing a query in mongodb using find() and i am getting pymongo cursor object and then i have to convert into list in python.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db = client['MarketData']
collection_name = db['FUTURE_ACC']

start_date = datetime(2015, 2, 2)
end_date = datetime(2015, 3, 2)

query = {"CandleDate": {"$gte": start_date,
                        "$lte": end_date}}

start_time = datetime.now()
data = list(collection_name.find(query))
print(data)
end_time = datetime.now()
print("Total Time:", (end_time - start_time))
```

I want to get directly list of dictionary or any Iterable( I know object is also iterable but i do not know how can i perform operations on it. Like we do in list of dict  --->  data[0]['Close'] )

Why i want directly list of dictionary is when i will be dealing with big data it will increase my time complexity.
even i use for loop like this to access the data.
`for i in data:`

`print(i)`

If i use for loop it will also increase my time complexity.

Edit:

```
data = [doc for doc in collection_name.find(query, projection)]

period = 5
close_price_list = [doc['Close'] for doc in data]

sma_list = [None, None, None, None]

for i in range(len(close_price_list) + period - 1):
    window = close_price_list[i:i + period]
    if len(window) == 5:
        sma = sum(window) / period
        sma_list.append(round(sma, 2))
```

After Getting list i will be doing this to calculate SMA.

Comment: Find will return a cursor which is an iterable. If you want a list, just use list() as you did in the code you provided

Comment: @Fourchette but it will increase when i  am dealing with big data.

Comment: I you want to use a list, just use one. But i don't even get why you would access a specific elem in your results.
You have an iterable, iterate on it. No better way.

Comment: I have Edited the question what i will be doing after getting a list.

Comment: If you want to calculate an SMA, you should consider using aggregate to query instead of find. Since mongo 5.0 you can use the `$setWindowFields` stage with the average operator. Here is some good documentation for you : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/#use-documents-window-to-obtain-moving-average-quantity-for-each-year
If you need more help just ask.